# preparecurvefit on different Matlab versions?

Tags: matlab

Thanks in advance for any help.  I am having trouble with my custom equation fitting.  First question is -- is there a fundamental difference between Matlab 2010 and 2013?  I created this code in 2013 on my work computer, but have not upgraded from 2010 on my personal computer...the code works on my work computer, and not my personal one.  Yes, the txt file is in the same folder as the matlab file.  So I don't get it.

Here is the code, if you wish to see it.  It has the error: Undefined function or method 'prepareCurveData' for input arguments of type 'double'

```
function [fitresult, gof] = createFit(v, dL)
filename='results.txt';
A=importdata(filename);
v=A.data(:,2);
L=A.data(:,3);
s=A.data(1,6);
dL=L-L(1);

%% Fit: 'untitled fit 1'.
[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData( v, dL );

% Set up fittype and options.
ft = fittype( 'x*3E-6/(k+x)', 'independent', 'x', 'dependent', 'y' );
opts = fitoptions( ft );
opts.Display = 'Off';
opts.Lower = -Inf;
opts.StartPoint = [];
opts.TolFun = 1e-20;
opts.TolX = 1e-20;
opts.Upper = Inf;

% Fit model to data.
[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume that code written for the latest version for MATLAB will work on all previous versions.

Either:

1) This function doesn't exist in 2010(a/b?)

2) You don't have the right toolbox or version of the toolbox on the computer running the older version.

3) The input requirements have changed (unlikely in this case)

4) The path to the function is broken (unlikely if other functions in the toolbox are working)

It is not easy to determine in which version of MATLAB a function was introduced. `exist prepareCurveData` will show you if that function can be found on the MATLAB path. `ver('curvefit')` will show you if you have the curve fitting toolbox, and what version it is.

In this particular case, since `prepareCurveData` appears to just be a bit of input checking, it wouldn't be hard to write your own.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I ended up just writing a new code to do the same thing...but I wanted to see if someone knew.  It will be rather annoying if I run into this problem often.  Thanks for your response!